# General understanding of the Google Cloud Storage billing and the GB-Day value

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a question regarding the general billing method of Google Cloud Storage. If I understand it correct they calculate the monthly cost by summing up the GB-day values.
So, what if I have, for example, 50GB for only three hours on my storage and after that 3h those 50GB are deleted and the storage is empty again.
Is then the GB-day = 50GB and the GB-Month = 50GB?

Further, three extended examples (Note: "empty again" means for the rest of the month):

1. 50GB for 1h (after that 1h the storage is empty again) -> 50GB-day -> 50GB GB-Month
2. 50GB for 3h (after that 3h the storage is empty again) -> 50GB-day -> 50GB GB-Month
3. 50GB for 1day and 3h (after that 1d3h the storage is empty again) -> 50GB-day (day one) and 50GB-day (day two) -> 100GB GB-Month

Are those calculations correct?

And further: What if I have something like that:
50GB for 2h and after those 2h I add 50GB for another 2h and then delete all data.
So I have:

1. For the first 2h: 50GB
2. For the second 2h: 100GB
3. Rest of the day: 0GB

Is then the GB-day 100GB or 150GB?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage costs are prorated and on a per-object basis. For instance, if you have a 1 GB object that exists for 12 hours, the resulting charge will be 1/2 GB-day = 1/2 * 1/30 GB-month.

To use your example, a 50 GB object that is deleted after 1 h would incur charges of 50 * 1/24 * 1/30 GB-month (the other cases work the same)

In your second example, the overall charges would be 50 * 2/24 * 1/30 GB-month + 100 * 2/24 * 1/30 GB-month.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thank you for your clear answer!

But, I have a follow-up question. 
What is the minimum time a used storage is charged? I saw that for the Compute Engine, Google charge for the use of minutes (except of the first 10min), but I wasn’t able to find anything about the cloud storage.
  
For example, if I have a 1GB file stored for only 30minutes. 
Is it then: 30/60 * 1/24 * 1/30 GB-month
Or is the smallest time unit 1h and therefore: 1/24 * 1/30GB-month

Again, thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no minimum time for storage -- if you delete something after 1 second you will only be charged for 1 second. The one exception is Nearline storage where objects are charged for at least 30 days (but this is very explicit in the documentation, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#nearline-pricing)